# svn move command is not as expected

Tags: svn

I use svn move to move a file from one dir to another dir.
After that, svn status output like below

```
D       xxx/xxx/AA/foo.txt
        > moved to xxx/xxx/AA/foo.txt
A  +    xxx/xxx/BB/foo.txt
        > moved from xxx/xxx/BB/foo.txt
```

And svn diff can display deletion
I thinkg "+" means "History scheduled with commit." So I use "svn add"
But svn complained  the file is already under version control

So how can I remove the "+"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `svn help move` output, we have:

> Fourth column: Scheduled commit will create a copy
>   (addition-with-history)
>
> `' '` no history scheduled with commit (item was newly added)
>
> `'+'` history scheduled with commit (item was copied)

So the `+` merely means the designated entry was
"added with history" — that is, you will be able to trace its history
past its appearance in the commit to be recorded.

`D` and `A` designators means that the respective entries will be deleted
and added.

In other words, what you're observing is the consequence of the fact
Subversion does not really records in the repository your *actions* in the sense it won't record something like «file "X" has been renamed to "Y"»
but it rather records renames as disappearance of the original entry
and appearance of a new entry *with history* — which is the history
of the original entry.

#### TL;DR

It's OK, just `svn commit` your rename.

Comment: Or in other words, getting rid of the `+` would mean losing the history and making it look like you deleted one file and added a new unrelated file.

Comment: @tripleee, I now wonder if that was the OP's actual question (i.e. they had assumed `svn move` "detaches" the target entry from the source's history). If yes, they could get away by doing `svn rm --keep-local SOURCE` followed by `mv SOURCE DEST && svn add DEST`.